# How to loop over text in a file and send output using sendmail?

Tags: macos, bash, email, sendmail

I'm trying to loop over each line in a text file where each line is a URL and then send each line from the same email address, to the same email address using sendmail.

I'm running OS X and doing trying to do this with a bash script and this is what I have so far

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line
    echo $line | sendmail -f myemmailaddress@gmail.com add@getpocket.com
done < readinglistlinksfromsafari.txt
```

Problem is, the messages sent are all empty, even though the links echo out correctly. What do you think this could be?

I'm fairly new to this so you'll have to forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to send them all in a single email message, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail expect header and body separated by empty line.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f myemmailaddress@gmail.com add@getpocket.com <<END
Subject: MySubject
From: myemmailaddress@gmail.com
To: add@getpocket.com

$line
END
done < readinglistlinksfromsafari.txt
```